# Msbuild fails with error message "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Tags: msbuild

Msbuild throws me an exception when i started to build my application. If any one has any idea about this error please let me know.

```
Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Build.Shared.InternalErrorException: MSB0001: Internal MSBuild Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
=============
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.AddMetaprojectReferenceItems(ProjectInstance traversalProject, ProjectInstance metaprojectInstance, ProjectInSolution project)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateMetaproject(ProjectInstance traversalProject, ProjectInSolution project, ProjectConfigurationInSolution projectConfiguration)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.EvaluateAndAddProjects(List`1 projectsInOrder, List`1 projectInstances, ProjectInstance traversalInstance, String selectedSolutionConfiguration)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateSolutionProject(String wrapperProjectToolsVersion, Boolean explicitToolsVersionSpecified)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.Generate()
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.GenerateSolutionWrapper(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.LoadSolutionForBuild(String projectFile, PropertyDictionary`1 globalPropertiesInstances, String toolsVersion, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.LoadSolutionIntoConfiguration(BuildRequestConfiguration config, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.HandleNewRequest(Int32 node, BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.BuildManager.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.INodePacketHandler.PacketReceived(Int32 node, INodePacket packet)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeManager.RoutePacket(Int32 nodeId, INodePacket packet)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeProviderInProc.RoutePacket(Int32 nodeId, INodePacket packet)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.NodeEndpointInProc.SendData(INodePacket packet)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.InProcNode.OnNewRequest(BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestEngine.RaiseRequestBlocked(BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestEngine.IssueBuildRequest(BuildRequestBlocker blocker)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.BuildRequestEngine.ReportConfigurationResponse(BuildRequestConfigurationResponse response)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.InProcNode.HandlePacket(INodePacket packet)
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.InProcNode.Run(Exception& shutdownException)

---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.AddMetaprojectReferenceItems(ProjectInstance traversalProject, ProjectInstance metaprojectInstance, ProjectInSolution project)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateMetaproject(ProjectInstance traversalProject, ProjectInSolution project, ProjectConfigurationInSolution projectConfiguration)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.EvaluateAndAddProjects(List`1 projectsInOrder, List`1 projectInstances, ProjectInstance traversalInstance, String selectedSolutionConfiguration)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.CreateSolutionProject(String wrapperProjectToolsVersion, Boolean explicitToolsVersionSpecified)
at Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionProjectGenerator.Generate()
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.GenerateSolutionWrapper(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext)
at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.LoadSolutionForBuild(String projectFile, PropertyDictionary`1 globalPropertiesInstances, String toolsVersion, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext projectBuildEventContext)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal error.  You can tell by the exception type, as well as by the error code (MSB0001).  It means that it will only happen with certain MSBuild versions and probably only with some particular project files.

I have seen cases where a similar error appeared in VS2010 and was fixed with subsequent versions.  I have seen cases where it did not appear with VS2013 and was introduced with either VS2015 or VS2017 (did not check all versions).  Those cases likely weren't related.

To ask a proper question about an internal tool problem you need to spend some 
time modifying (simplifying) your projects until you know what kind of project file change (or source file change) turns this problem on and off, and with which tool version(s).